# Why did Orthodox Christians alter the liturgy of St. John Chrysostom to pray for "Orthodox" Christians?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, schism

I'm a Catholic who also attends Eastern Orthodox services, mainly Greek.  One of the most bizarre differences between Catholics and Orthodox is that the Orthodox service regularly reminds everyone that they're Orthodox.

However, in the liturgy of St. John Chrysostom, both in the "original" Greek, and the translated English, regularly mentions that "we pray for all pious and Orthodox Christians".

This liturgy was written some time around the year 400 A.D., at which point the Church was relatively unified compared to today.  At least Constantinople and Rome were together.  So I think that the inclusion of the word "Orthodox" is unlikely to be original.

Furthermore, I noticed that in the ROCOR service which is a "translation" of the Roman Mass, they again added the word "Orthodox", which seems *highly unlikely* to be within the original text.

As a Catholic, I was taught in childhood that yes, Christianity has broken up into different sects, but that doesn't make us any better.  The Orthodox seem to have taken the exact opposite approach, as the sect-consciousness is *much stronger* there than among Catholics or Protestants.

The addition of "Orthodox" may seem trivial, but the Orthodox make a big deal about being the original unchanged church, which seems to be very doubtful to me.

I've asked an Orthodox priest about the addition of this word, but he doesn't know, and seemed bothered by the question, honestly.  I was very surprised.

Why/when/who added the "Orthodox" to the service?

Comment: "but that doesn't make us any better." Catholics and the Orthodox (and many Protestants) have this sort of teaching. Most obviously from the Catholics, the creed: I believe in one holy, Catholic and apostolic church. As any Protestant who has debated with Catholics will attest, there's a LOT of Catholic teaching on how it's the one true church. See e.g. the Council of Trent, or the podcast of similar name today. It's very damaging to the church IMO and this stack's excessive focus on denominational teaching furthers it in a small way, also IMO.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant the Orthodox and Lutherans both use the term "Catholic" which means "universal" it's not referring to the RC church, specifically.  The word "Catholic" doesn't appear in the Mass outside the creed, and is rarely mentioned in homilies.

Comment: Catholics definitely should be teaching you that we (Catholics) are the best Christian group, we're the one Holy Catholic and Apostolic Church. On the creed thing, that creed was written before any split, and the word Catholic means universal. Eastern Orthodox Christians hold that they are the true Catholic (ie universal ) Church. They are not, we Catholics are.

Comment: @Con Most Protestants are careful to use a lower case 'c'. Not sure about Lutherans though.

Comment: @jaredad7 Yes, that's the Catholic position (I'm a Protestant and disagree, the church is the body of all true bellievers, but I digress). I concluded the answer mischaracterised it.

Comment: Which ROCOR service are you referring to that is a translation of the Roman Mass.  ROCOR would more likely translate from the Slavonic.

Comment: @guest37 ROCOR translated the Roman Mass, presumably from Latin

Comment: Which specific translation are you referring to?  The service in the Jordanville Prayer Book or any of the Jordanville books?  That is certainly from the Slavonic and not Latin.  The Latin Mass is from an entirely different rite in any case.  It is not the Liturgy of John Chrysostom.